# how to receive form data submitted with jquery submit()

Tags: php, jquery, forms

How can I get the form data if the form is submitted with jQuery `submit()` function? 
For example

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" id="someForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
</form>
```

Which I submit with jQuery like:

```
$("#someForm").submit();
```

How can I get receive the fields name and email if the form is submitted?
Thanks

Comment: Exactly like if the form had been submitted manually. `$_POST["fieldname"]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$('#name').val()` and `$('#email').val()` in the submit callback(

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    alert($('#name').val());
});
```

for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
  $_POST["name"]

  $_POST["email"]
```

You can get fields by their names. Hope I made it clear.